# Multi Authentication Problem in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel-7

I use 2 authentication method in Laravel 7 Project. Default auth and manual auth. Default auth uses for User and manual auth for admin. But in manual auth when credentials given then the route redirect back. Please any one help me. I can't understand the error, Where I missing anything.

Here is my route:

```
//Admin Authentication
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('adminLogin');
Route::post('/adminLogin', 'AdminController@adminLogin');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () { 
Route::get('/admin/home', 'AdminController@adminHome')->name('adminHome');
Route::post('adminLogout', 'AdminController@adminLogout');
});
```

Admin Controller:

```
public function adminLogin(Request $request)
{
$this->validator($request);    
if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($request->only('email','password'),$request->filled('remember'))){
    //Authentication passed...
    return redirect('/admin/home')->with('success','You are Logged in as Admin!');
}
//Authentication failed...
return $this->loginFailed();
}
```

Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
{
    if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/admin');
    }
    return $next($request);
    }
```

Handler:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }
        if ($request->is('admin') || $request->is('admin/*')) {
            return redirect()->guest('/admin');
        }      
        return redirect()->guest(route('index'));
    }
```

Login Form:

```
 <form role="form" action="{{ url('/adminLogin') }}" method="post">
                @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <a href="#" class="pull-right label-forgot">Forgot email?</a>
                        <label for="inputUsernameEmail">Username or email</label>
                        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <a href="#" class="pull-right label-forgot">Forgot password?</a>
                        <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox pull-left">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">
                        Log In
                    </button>
                </form>
```